# Generate ERD Diagram from Spring Boot Application Source Code

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I thought it would be obvious to automatically generate an Entity-Relation Diagram **(ERD)** from **Hibernate-annotated** source code in **Spring Boot**, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I was expecting to find a maven plugin to provide the functionality but didn't find one. This is why I am addressing the Spring community for advice.

Had anyone already have to do this type of reverse engineering in order to generate the ERD diagram from Spring Boot source code?

I need this actually to better document the data used and consumed by a big system made of more that 20 micro-services where existing documentation is not good / complete enough and does not reflect the current state of the system.

I already had an idea to start from swagger to generate the controller / model documentation and to convert that to UML / ERD, but didn't find the good tools neither.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you want a tool/library recommendation. It's off-topic

Comment: yes, it could be a tool or just a compiler configuration. as the source code is already annotated, I expected Compiler + Basic IDE to be capable of doing that.

Comment: Its sounds like, instead of asking from Boeing company I am asking Spring Boot to give blue print for 737. LOL.

Comment: that's right, but unlike huge industries who write huge specs, software development has become more lean, more about writing code quickly & doing agile that providing accurate documentation. and with micro-services things are getting messy. manually doing the research and finding all references isn't an easy task honestly :D

Comment: It is not from the code, but https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler-Report-Maven-Plugin helps to generate the ER diagram from the database connection, it could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

ERD is a database diagram that you could generate from a database with according tools. For example IntelliJ or DBeaver.

UML you can generate with IntelliJ as well.

But what you are probably looking for are tools like Structure101 that will generate dependency graphs and layered diagrams to understand the code.

These tools are usually not for free.

Comment: Actually I was trying to avoid  having to export it from the database because I only have access to the code, but this is maybe the way to go as you said. Still, swagger can link the api to model, this is why I was trying to focus on the code.

Comment: But Swagger documentation is kind of fallout. Swagger intention is to create a api specification like SOAPs WSDL was in the past.